# How to make Bluetooth RFCOMM device persistent across restarts

Tags: bluetooth, devices

I am using an HC-06 bluetooth device to communicate from a peripheral to a Ubuntu 20 program using the PCs internal bluetooth device. The Bluetooth desktop manager has paired it. From terminal, I can bind it with:`sudo rfcomm bind 0 <mac addr>`
and then point my Linux program to use device rfcomm0 as the comm port and it works fine...

but the bind is lost upon restart...how can I automatically recreate the bind at startup every time....I have tried using the command as a Startup Application and that does not work

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  No such release, so do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to the more common Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Ubuntu releases using the *year* format are *snap* only, compared to the more powerful *year.month* format that can use *deb*, *snap* packages are more).  Please clarify

Comment: shorthand Ubuntu 20.04lts desktop....in older versions you could add an entry in /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf to create the device bind during bluetooth service initialization, but that capability was apparently dropped  before the Unbuntu 18.04lts  release...

Comment: Ubuntu has used the *year* format for products that are *snap* only since 2016, so Ubuntu 20 implies a *snap* only system that was intended for *headless* operation (ie. cut-down Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server).  The *year* format are different products and not a shorthand; a smaller less powerful product, which is beneficial in cloud, device & certain setups (faster to spin up etc).  Applications in 20 are run in containerized environments without access to the real file-system (with some exceptions; eg. *classic* confinement) so configs are different between 20 & 20.04